# printing unique variants for all products on top of a collection page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to create a filter on top of a collection page with all the available variants.  But, I need them to be formatted nicely so I'm using the following code:

```
{% for product in collections.all.products limit: limit %}
<li>

{% assign sizes = product.variants | map: 'option1' | uniq %}

{% assign colors = product.variants | map: 'option2' | uniq %}


{% assign combined_variants = sizes | concat: colors | uniq %}

{% for v-item in combined_variants %}
    {{ v-item }} <br/>
{% endfor %}

</li> 
{% endfor %}

{{ combined_variants | json }}
```

The problem is that I need it to iterate through all the products but only print unique values across all of them.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off creating custom collections for each option. Put all Size X in collection Size X. Put all Yellow Budgies in collection Yellow Budgies. Then you can craft a navigation scheme that takes customers to the products that fit their selection. All things Size X, or all things Yellow Budgie.

Building out a different filter could also be the JSON approach using the Mega Menus like Bacon etc. They deliver a payload to your them that can help customers drill to what they want. You have no easy way of doing this yourself with the code you are presenting.